# Accessing a SFTP Server - are keys necessary, if yes which public or private

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, sftp

We have been given a Username and Password for a remote SFTP Server (hosted by someone else).

My SFTP Client program (that i use) asks for Keys to proceed.
What key should i ask the SFTP provider to give us - public or private?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not require keys in order to access a remote host using `sftp`.  Either key-based or password-based access will work just fine, barring explicit configuration on the remote server to require one or the other.

In order to use ssh keys, you will need to first generate an ssh keypair and then place the *public* key in the appropriate place on the remote server.  Exactly how to do this depends on what client you're using and what sort of access you have to the remote host.

In general: *you* would generate keys and provide the public key to the provider.  It's possible that they may do it the other way (generate they keys and give you the private key), but this is less typical.

Comment: Well, to be clear, it is *possible* that the host has disable password-based auth for security (which is a good idea).

Comment: I had actually updated the answer to reflect that while you were writing that comment :).

Comment: If the hoster had done that he wouldnt provide a username and pass instead he would ask for a public key to add to authorized keys

Comment: It's always a possibility.  There are some odd policies out there!